# Reading an Excel File (Excelfinlename.dvd) with decimal comma instaed of decimal point?

Tags: matlab

Currently i am trying to read an excel files with two different ending . dvd & .sod (From SCADA system). i am using the [Values] = xlsread(File_to_Open) to do so. my question is: In the excel file i have the values so written (Example: 21,1) with comma not point (I am using a German Windows system) and when i am importing those data to matlab i am getting something like 37, I am not sure why!! Can you help me with this problem of importing when using the xlsread() function?

```
Example for my Excel Data is as following:
Date    Hour    Minute  Second  PlantNo Error   arDevV1 arDevV2 Temp.
01.07.2013  0   0   0   1   0   0,0 0,0 20,1
01.07.2013  0   0   0   2   0   0,0 0,0 20,6
01.07.2013  0   0   0   3   0   0,0 0,0 20,4
01.07.2013  0   0   0   4   0   0,0 0,0 20,7
01.07.2013  0   0   0   5   0   0,0 0,0 20,9
01.07.2013  0   0   0   6   0   0,0 0,0 20,6
01.07.2013  0   0   0   7   0   0,0 0,0 163,2
01.07.2013  0   1   0   1   0   0,0 0,0 20,1
01.07.2013  0   1   0   2   0   0,0 0,0 20,5
01.07.2013  0   1   0   3   0   0,0 0,0 20,3
01.07.2013  0   1   0   4   0   0,0 0,0 20,7
```

and i am getting in matlab the following:

```
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   37
0   0   0   2   0   0   0,400000000000000   38
0   0   0   3   0   0   0   -43,6000000000000
0   0   0   4   0   0   0   37,8000000000000
0   0   0   5   0   0   0,300000000000000   39,5000000000000
0   0   0   6   246 0   0   0
0   0   1   7   0   0   0   38,8000000000000
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   37
0   1   0   2   0   0   0,400000000000000   38
0   1   0   3   0   0   0   -43,6000000000000
0   1   0   4   0   0   0   37,8000000000000
0   1   0   5   0   0   0,300000000000000   39,5000000000000
0   1   0   6   246 0   0   0
0   1   1   7   0   0   0   38,7000000000000
0   2   0   1   0   0   0   36,9000000000000
0   2   0   2   0   0   0,400000000000000   38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using only Matlab:

you could try to use the raw-output and replace comma with dot. You get the raw data as the third output of xlsread:

> [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(*_*) additionally returns the text fields in cell array txt, and the unprocessed data (numbers and text) in cell array raw using any of the input arguments in the previous syntaxes. If xlRange is specified, leading blank rows and columns in the worksheet that precede rows and columns with data are returned in raw.

What would be better in my opinion, is to change comma to dot within Excel. At the moment, matlab (or xlsread) is interpreting the data as something else.

Comment: do you have a function that can do this change between comma and point directly?
that can help me save some time

Comment: well quick and dirty, it should look like this: loop over every single element within the raw-data and use strrep(raw(indx,indy),',''.'). I dont have enough time today to test it:( Perhaps someone else has...

Comment: Thx very much for the help, i simply used the Cell2mat function to get the needed values :) i save some time not using a for loop ^^